# Specifying full range of printable ASCII characters in a glob pattern

Tags: bash, wildcards, glob

I want to use a globbing pattern to match only printable (including space) ASCII characters `0x20` through to `0x7e`. This is being used inside a [`super`](http://www.ucolick.org/%7Ewill/RUE/super/super.1.html) [`super.tab`](http://www.ucolick.org/%7Ewill/RUE/super/super.5.html) database.

I've arrived at the pattern:

`[[ -~]]`

This appears to work and does indeed restrict non-printing characters from being passed as arguments.

Have I over looked anything, or is this the correct way to specify this range of characters?

**Edit:**

Based on *mikeserv*'s suggestion to use `[[:print:]]`, I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what the entry in my `super.tab` looks like:

```
dosuperthing  /system/dosuperthing.pl $Users  uid=0 arg1="[[:print:]]"
```

If I try `[[:print:]]`, `[:print:]` or `:print:` as globbing patterns for `arg1` it results in (respectively) the following being logged by `super` where I pass `abcdef` as my first argument:

> `super: (admin) Your argument #1 <abcdef> must match pattern <[[:print:]]>`
>
> `super: (admin) Your argument #1 <abcdef> must match pattern <[:print:]>`
>
> `super: (admin) Your argument #1 <abcdef> must match pattern <:print:>`

This is old legacy production code and I'm not able to tinker with it beyond tuning the acceptable `arg1-99` patterns inside `super.tab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glob pattern or regular expression `[ -~]` matches all printable characters in the C locale: this matches all characters from 32 (space) to 126 (tilde). In a locale other than C (more precisely, if `LC_COLLATE` is not C), if the application is locale-aware, this may match other characters.

Another way to write this pattern is `[[:print:]]`. However, this matches all printable characters in the current locale (based on the `LC_CTYPE` setting), so it's no better than `[ -~]` for your use case. Also, it may not work if your application or system library is too antiquated to understand the `[:class:]` syntax.

Super's `[[cHARS]]` syntax (if the global option `patterns=shell` is set) follows the same principle, so it's `[[ -~]]` to mean “printable ASCII characters only”. Super doesn't set any locale other than `LC_CTYPE`, so you're safe from that front. Make sure that `patterns=shell` *is* set; the default is `patterns=regex`, which requires that you write `^[ -~]*$` instead.

Comment: As always, another excellent and detailed answer chap.